# ms excel turn columns into rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to take an excel spread sheet and change the columns to rows. The sheet is currently designed like this.

```
Employee Name   Expiration 1     Expiration 2    Expiration  3  Expiration 4
John Doe
Jane Doe
```

What I need to do is convert it to this

```
Employee Name    Expiration     Date
John Doe             1           12-12-12
John Doe             2           12-12-12
John Doe             3           12-12-12
John Doe             4           12-12-12
Jane Doe             1           12-1-12
Jane Doe             2           12-1-12
Jane Doe             3           12-1-12
Jane Doe             4           12-1-12
```

I am not even sure if this is possible.

Comment: The [tag:excel] tag has turned into a bad joke.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply with an `INDEX(MATCH(),MATCH())` formula.

This screenshot should be enough to get you started:

[Screenshot(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVaA4.png)

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: I have tried the formula and cant seem to get it to work for me. The formula I used is =INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:Sheet1!$E$4,MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!$A$1:Sheet1!$A$3,0),MATCH(Sheet2!B1,Sheet1!$A$1:Sheet1!$A$3,0))  I get a #NA error

Comment: Hi Josh, it looks like your INDEX range (rows 1-4) is larger than your MATCH range (rows 1-3) which is your first issue. Secondly you are matching the rows twice instead of the rows, then columns as in my example. It might help to practice on the same sheet as your lookup so you can see the coloured squares to aid in your understanding. Here is a link to a tutorial on INDEX MATCH: http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/  Good luck!